# What are the ways to change a variable's value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I read before that the only way to change the value a variable holds is using an assignment operator (`=`, `+=`,  ..)
But in this example from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/CONCAT), **`nums`** variable returns two *different* values by changing one of the arrays used in the assignment without using an assignment operator.

```js
var num1 = [[1]];
var num2 = [2, [3]];

var nums = num1.concat(num2);
console.log(nums);

num1[0].push(4);
console.log(nums);
```

However, when I remove the nested array and just push `4` to `num2` array directly, the printed value doesn't change.
Check this [example](http://jsbin.com/zapikaw/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function returns a new array, comprised of the elements of both arrays.

In the first case, the `num1` array and `nums` contains references to the same inner array, so when you change it, it is reflected in both.

In the second case, the arrays contain numbers, and there is nothing shared between the arrays. That's why when you push to one, the other doesn't change.

As for the assignment confusion, `nums` always points to the same array until you assign a new value to nums. That doesn't mean you can't change the contents of the array itself.

Comment: That's right. For further info, read a complete description of concat: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation Nimord